# Is it possible to launch Spring Batch Job via JMX / visualvm?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Is it possible to launch Spring Batch Job via JMX / visualvm?

Do I need dependency:

```
compile("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-manager")
```

Docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/reference/jmx.html doesn't mention possibility to launch job. Only to monitor job stats.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but I guess you will need to use spring-integration too. 
You need to setup integration to listen on JMX and then pipe it to channel which then will be listened by some requestTransformer:

```
public class SomethingToJobLaunchRequestTransformer extends AbstractSmthTransformer<JobLaunchRequest> {

  private Job job;

  public void setJob(Job job) {
      this.job = job;
  }

  @Override
  protected final JobLaunchRequest transformSomething(Something smt) {
      JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
      //put your something into job parameters....
      return new JobLaunchRequest(job, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
  }

}
```

And finally pass it to `JobLaunchingGateway`

For more details please check [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html), it contains good example.